# How to write this homogeneous polynomial as a sum of monomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, monomial-function

I have the following product of monomials in $x$:

\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k\leq n} x_{i_1} \cdots x_{i_k} \right)^{m_k},
\end{align*}
where $\sum_{k=1}^n k m_k = N$ for some $N\geq n$ und the $m_k$ are supposed to be non-negative integers.
This turns out to be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $N$. I was wondering if there is good way to write this as a sum of monomials like
\begin{align*}
\sum_{l_1 + \cdots + l_n = N} C_{l_1,\dots,l_n} x_1^{l_1} \cdots x_n^{l_n}.
\end{align*}
I want to write down the coefficients $C_{l_1,\dots,l_n}$ explicitly, so I hope that someone has seen this before and can help me.